How to search for items in Sitecore Content Editor using short IDs without manually adding dashes?
I'm working with Solr queries that reference items by their short IDs (e.g., 87a46235118d498eb379936701551737). These IDs correspond to my content items in Sitecore.
I often use the Content Editor search bar to find specific items using GUIDs, but when I try to search for items with short IDs, no results appear unless I manually insert the dashes to convert them into the GUID format.
Is there a way to configure Sitecore to handle short IDs directly in the search bar, or is there an alternative method I can use to quickly locate these items without needing to modify the ID format manually?
Short ID Search

GUID Search


As Dean mentioned, searching by short IDs actually should work. However, an alternative / stopgap solution is a bookmarklet that instantly converts a short ID to a GUID (or vice versa) and copies it to the clipboard for easy pasting:
javascript:(function(){
  let input = prompt("Enter a short ID (e.g. 673b8f8b65188005afa4e660d3a74231) or a GUID (e.g. 673b8f8b-6518-8005-afa4-e660d3a74231):");
  if (!input) return;
  let output;
  if (input.length === 32) {
    output = input.replace(/(.{8})(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})(.{12})/, "$1-$2-$3-$4-$5");
  } else if (input.length === 36 && /^[0-9a-fA-F\-]+$/.test(input)) {
    output = input.replace(/-/g, "");
  } else {
    return;
  }
  let textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
  textarea.value = output;
  document.body.appendChild(textarea);
  textarea.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  document.body.removeChild(textarea);
})();


I just tried a couple of searches (Sitecore 10.3) using short IDs and both came back with a hit.
First was bottom right on desktop:

Second was main search bar on the content editor:

The later is obviously the same as your search, which is strange... I get the same result using lowercase letters also.
